# How to do SEO link tag for two/multiple pagination in single page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, seo

I wrote an application in rails 4. In that app, I have two pagination in single page 'x (page)'. Params like groups and page in the url.

```
Url looks like:
https://example.com/x?page=2&group=4
Initial page:
https://example.com/x
If pagination page params, then
https://example.com/x?page=2
If paginating groups params, then
https://example.com/x?group=2
If paginating both,then
https://example.com/x?page=2&group=2
and so on.
```

I am using Kaminari gem to do pagination. In that gem I used rel_next_prev_link_tags helper to show link tag for prev/next.

How to show link tags for multiple pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an custom helper to process the URL and based on params create the categorized link tags. ex: In view,

```
pagination_link_tags(@pages,'page') for pages pagination
pagination_link_tags(@groups,'group') for groups pagination

def pagination_link_tags(collection,pagination_params)
    output = []
    link = '<link rel="%s" href="%s"/>'
    url = request.fullpath
    uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
    parameters = uri.query_values
    # Update the params based on params name and create a link for SEO
    if parameters.nil?
      if collection.next_page
        parameters = {}
        parameters["#{pagination_params}"] = "#{collection.next_page}"
        uri.query_values = parameters
        output << link % ["next", uri.to_s]
      end
    else
      if collection.previous_page
        parameters["#{pagination_params}"] = "#{collection.previous_page}"
        uri.query_values = parameters
        output << link % ["prev", uri.to_s]
      end
      if collection.next_page
        parameters["#{pagination_params}"] = "#{collection.next_page}"
        uri.query_values = parameters
        output << link % ["next", uri.to_s]
      end
    end
    output.join("\n").html_safe
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't show search engines two-dimensional pagination. In your case it looks more like grouping/categorizing + pagination.

Like:

```
Group 1 pages:
https://example.com/x
https://example.com/x?page=2
https://example.com/x?page=3
Group 2 pages:
https://example.com/x?group=2
https://example.com/x?page=2&group=2
https://example.com/x?page=3&group=2
```

Etc.